# Collecting Tabular Input with AJAX

Tags: ajax, yii, tabular

I want to use tabular data collection but I am facing some problems with it. see as you have to use

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]name"); ?>
```

with
key in above it is `$i` 
this will eventually help traversing through all records while we are in controller.

**Now what the problem is ?**
I am trying to implement via

```
AJAX
```

. Now i need some sort of variable to keep track of index.That is what I am stuck with.

other wise my form gets fields added when I click add and they are just fine. How can you manage the index?

following is my complete code

**Controller**

```
public function actionAddHotelPictures($id,$key)
        {
            $model = new HotelImages;
            $this->render('hotelPicture',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
                    'key'=>$key,
            ));
        }
public function actionAddImageRow()
        {               
            $key = $_GET['key'];

            $this->renderPartial('_singleImageRow', array('key'=>$key, 'model'=>new HotelImages),false,true);

        }
```

**View**

```
<?php

echo CHtml::ajaxLink(Yii::app()->createUrl('/AddImageRow'),
        array('hotel/AddImageRow','key'=>++$key),
        array(
            'type' => 'GET',
            'update'=>'#asd',            
             'success' => "function( data )
                 {
                 alert(data)
                 //$('table tbody').append(data); 
                  }",
            'error'=>"function( xhr )
                 {
                    alert(this.url)
                  }",
            'data'=> array( 'key'=> ++$key )
            )
        );

            ?>
```

**_singleImageRow**

```
<tr>    

    <td>Image Title <?php echo $key;?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,"[$key]title"); ?></td>
    <td>Image</td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::fileField('Immagini[immagine]'); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Even I am incrementing $key in Ajax Function but I donot know why it still every time passes same value that is one increment to value that was orignally given from actionAddHotelPictures

for ex if 2 was passed as key then every time 3 is passed in ajax to actionAddImageRow no matter how many time you click it 
0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you sending  `$key` twice in the ajax link? Here:

`array('hotel/AddImageRow','key'=>++$key)`

and here:

```
 'data'=> array( 'key'=> ++$key )
```

Maybe it is causing some malfunction which corrupts the values.